# How to put the text of a JLabel under its icon

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, jlabel

I trying to put the text of a JLabel under its icon (centered)  at the momemnt I can get  this

[image: Current]

using  `JLabel north = new JLabel("North")`

I tried using html in the label `JLabel("<HTML><BR>North</HTML>")` but it is not aligned properly.  Any suggestions?

---

Answer (score 36, accepted):

See this:

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/LabelTextPosition.htm

Basically, use this in your case:

```
north.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
north.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
```